# Cannot modify a String in a MongoDb Database with router.post()

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, postman

I created an object within my MongoDb database.
The object has the following scheme:

```
var goalsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  types: [String],
  start: String,
  end: String,
 });

 var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  surname: String,
  email: String,
  goals: [goalsSchema],
    });
```

When I insert the object, through `router.post()`, everything works fine, But when I try to add a string inside the Types property, it doesn't work. The terminal tells me that everything worked, with `code 200`, but in reality the database is not updated.

This is code inside `index.js`:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

mongoose
  .connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/meditactive", {
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useNewUrlParser: true,
  })
  .then(() => console.log("Server connected"))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));

var db = mongoose.connection;

const goalsRouter = require("./routes/goals");

app.use(express.json());
app.use(mongoSanitize());

app.use("/api/goal", goalsRouter);

app.listen(3000);
```

while this is the one within `routes/goals`:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

router.post("/:id/goals/:idgoal/edit", (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;
  const { idgoal } = req.params;
  const goalInsert = req.body;

  User.findById(id)
    .then((user) => {
      if (user) {
        const goalToModify = user.goals.find(
          (goal) => goal._id.toString() === idgoal
        );
        console.log(goalToModify);

        if (goalToModify) {
          goalToModify.types.push(goalInsert);
          user.markModified("goals");
          user
            .save()
            .then(() => {
              res.status(200).json({ message: "Goals added" });
            })
            .catch((err) => {
              res.status(500).json({ error: err });
            });
        } else {
          res.status(500).json({ error: err });
        }
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.status(500).json({ error: err });
    });
});
```

I make the request with `Postman`, I send a string between double quotes, I receive the message: `Goals added` but inside types I see an empty object and not my string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this type of update you can use mongoose `findOneAndUpdate()` method. I will give an example using `async/await` as you seem to be heading for nested `then` blocks which can cause issues as your application grows.

```
router.post("/:id/goals/:idgoal/edit", async (req, res) => { //< Note the use of async keyword

   try { // Wrap in a try catch for cleaner error handling
      const { id } = req.params;
      const { idgoal } = req.params;
      const goalInsert = req.body;

      const user = await User.findOneAndUpdate( //< Note the use of await
            {
                _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id), //< Find user with this _id
                "goals._id": new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(idgoal), // But also with this idgoal
            },
            {
               $push: { //< Push in the goals.types array
                  "goals.$.types": goalInsert
               }
            }, {new: true} //< This option returns the updated document
     ); 
     console.log(user);

     res.status(200).json({ message: "Goals added" });

   } catch(err){
      res.status(500).json({ error: err });
   }
});
```

This uses [$push](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) to push the items to your `types` array.

If however, you need the `types` array to be a unique list of values in the array then you will need to use [$addToSet](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) instead like so.

```
const user = await User.findOneAndUpdate( //< Note the use of await
   {
      _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id), //< Find user with this _id
      "goals._id": new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(idgoal), // But also with this idgoal
   },
   {
      $addToSet: { //< Add unique value in the goals.types array
         "goals.$.types": goalInsert
      }
   }, {new: true} //< This option returns the updated document
);
```